# ABC-SMC, how to obtain summary statistics

Tags: bayesian, approximate-bayesian-computation, sequential-monte-carlo

I'm using the package [pyABC](https://pyabc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which implements the ABC-SMC algorithm. My model is described by fewer than 10 parameters.

I run the code with $N=50$ particles and stop the process after a maximum run time (I have to because the algorithm usually gets stuck at population ~30) This results in ~30 distributions for each parameter, where the last ones obviously come closer to the real PDF. Here's an example for a single $\mu$ parameter and 5 populations:

[image]

My question is: how do I obtain the statistical summaries (mean, median, STDDEV, etc..) for the model parameters? Do I use just the 50 particles from the latest population? Can (should) I use *all* the particles from *all* the populations?

Comment: What do you mean by "comes closer to the real pdf?" is this some simulation data where you know the truth?

Comment: No, I don't have the real PDF but that's how ABC-SMC works right? Each new population of particles comes closer to describing the actual PDF that you are trying to estimate.

Comment: I think you should only use the last population, although ideally you would sample until sample until the acceptance threshold epsilon drops below the specified value and then use the last population

Comment: Yes, you should use the last population of particles to approximate the posterior distribution, as it should correspond to the smallest tolerance level.

Comment: Then this means that 50 particles might not be enough to summarize the model parameters properly. Thank you both! If anyone would like to expand the comment into an answer, I'll accept it